# physical serial number in raid (windows)

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows

I am trying to get the physical serial numbers of hard drives in a raid array for equipment tracking purposes. I have tried a lot of wmic commands including:

`wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber`

While a the wmic commands seem to work great when dealing with regular, non raid hard drives.
I have started looking for APIs, and the best thing I have found is:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16941/Get-Physical-HDD-Serial-Number-without-WMI

After a good bit of tinkering I managed to get that to compile, but it can't even find the serial numbers on non raid hard drives. Part of that might be because I can't give it admin rights.

If there is a solution that requires admin rights, I can see what I can do.

Windows Versions: 7, and Server 2008/2012

This is a hardware RAID, but this needs to be able to be deployed on many platforms (HP/Dell/Custom servers and workstations across many generations).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of the RAID, if it's a hardware/firmware RAID you most likely will need some external tool provided by controller manufacturer.

From [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/76ab7322-004b-4dd0-8429-6089549dd186/wmi-class-suport-for-raid-arrays?forum=netfxbcl):

> In general, if it is hardware RAID then you need some add-on software
>   to help you do the query. That is because the job of the RAID
>   controller is to present a single logical disk drive to the OS (and
>   BIOS) rather than individual disk drives.

Comment: It seems to be possible to read information behind raid. "I have 5 drives installed. I have one Crucial M4 SSD which shows smart status in the system details, but no temperature is reported in the sensors. I also have a 2 TB Western Digital Drive (WD20EARS) which reports everything fine including temp. And then I have three WD 500 GB drives (2 WD5000AAKS and 1 WD5000AACS) set up in a raid 5. All three of these seem to report their smart status and temperatures fine - current temps are 26, 27, 24"http://www.hwinfo.com/forum/Thread-Solved-Can-HWiNFO-read-disk-temps-behind-Intel-RST-RAID